# increment values in maya python

Tags: python, random, increment, maya

```
randoms = [rand.uniform(-1,1)for items in range(10)]
x= 0
for i in List:
    cm.setKeyframe(at = "%s.cv[x].xValue"%i , t=5, v=rand.choice(randoms))
    x+=1
```

this part of code that i wanna use,  but maya can't accept this [x].
someone told me you should do this:

```
for i in List:
    x = 0
    cvAttrX = i+".cv["+str(x)+"].xValue"
    cm.setKeyframe(at = cvAttrX , t=5, v=rand.choice(randoms))
    x+=1
```

but i got this error:

```
# Error: line 1: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<maya console>", line 1, in <module>
#   File "<maya console>", line 7, in randList
# TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list #
```

if someone fix this please explain that deeply to me.
i wanna learn this one very good 
and please fix this example too:

```
randoms = [rand.uniform(cm.floatField(Ceil, q = True , v = True),0.5)for i in range(30)]
    for objects in myList:
        cm.xform('%s.cv[0]'%objects , r = True , t = [(rand.choice(randoms)),(rand.choice(randoms)),(rand.choice(randoms))])
        cm.xform('%s.cv[1]'%objects , r = True , t = [(rand.choice(randoms)),(rand.choice(randoms)),(rand.choice(randoms))])
        cm.xform('%s.cv[2]'%objects , r = True , t = [(rand.choice(randoms)),(rand.choice(randoms)),(rand.choice(randoms))])
        cm.xform('%s.cv[3]'%objects , r = True , t = [(rand.choice(randoms)),(rand.choice(randoms)),(rand.choice(randoms))])
        cm.xform('%s.cv[4]'%objects , r = True , t = [(rand.choice(randoms)),(rand.choice(randoms)),(rand.choice(randoms))])
        cm.xform('%s.cv[5]'%objects , r = True , t = [(rand.choice(randoms)),(rand.choice(randoms)),(rand.choice(randoms))])
        cm.xform('%s.cv[6]'%objects , r = True , t = [(rand.choice(randoms)),(rand.choice(randoms)),(rand.choice(randoms))])
        cm.xform('%s.cv[7]'%objects , r = True , t = [(rand.choice(randoms)),(rand.choice(randoms)),(rand.choice(randoms))])
        cm.xform('%s.cv[8]'%objects , r = True , t = [(rand.choice(randoms)),(rand.choice(randoms)),(rand.choice(randoms))])
        cm.xform('%s.cv[9]'%objects , r = True , t = [(rand.choice(randoms)),(rand.choice(randoms)),(rand.choice(randoms))])
        cm.xform('%s.cv[10]'%objects , r = True , t = [(rand.choice(randoms)),(rand.choice(randoms)),(rand.choice(randoms))])
```

this is a part of my script if i can do increment i don't wanna write this line for exampla 100 time, i can make intField for that and determine how many do i need

i wanna do something like this but i don't know how

```
import maya.cmds as cm
import random as rand
myList = cm.ls(sl =True)
cvList = []
randomList = []
def Lister():
for i in myList:
    cvList.append(cm.ls('%s.cv[:]'%i , flatten = True))
    return cvList
def randomize():
    x = 0 
    randomList.append([rand.uniform(-1,1)for items in range(10)])
    for i in cvList:
        cm.setKeyframe(at = "%s.cv[x].xValue"%i , t=5, v=rand.choice(randoms))
        x+=1
```

Comment: This is probably not a maya issue because you are getting a generic Python error message. You are trying to concatenate lists and strings, these are two different types, you are not allowed to do that, you need to convert one type to another. What kind of items to you have in List variable? What type does maya expect as the value of at keyword argument? Without knowing this one can only guess that the problem probably lies here: 'cvAttrX = str(i)+".cv["+str(x)+"].xValue"'

Comment: myList contains cv info of two curve. myList = [['c1.cv[1]'],['c1.cv[2]'],until the end of list]

Answer (score 0):

```
myCurve = cm.ls(sl=1) # Will return [u'curve1']

# Since it returned the object in a list in the next command you have to subscript it.

myCVs = cm.ls(myCurve[0] + ".cv[:]", fl=1)


# Result: [u'curve1.cv[0]',
 u'curve1.cv[1]',
 u'curve1.cv[2]',
 u'curve1.cv[3]',
 u'curve1.cv[4]',
 u'curve1.cv[5]',
 u'curve1.cv[6]',
 u'curve1.cv[7]',
 u'curve1.cv[8]',
 u'curve1.cv[9]',
 u'curve1.cv[10]'] # 

# We do not need to increment through these, flatten takes care of that. We need only iterate through the list of cvs and concatenate the attribute to the name.

for i in myCVs:
    cm.setAttr(i + ".xValue", random.uniform(-1, 1))
    print cm.getAttr(i + ".xValue")

# This will move all the cvs on that curve by a random value between -1 and 1.

-0.233699187896
0.353531892619
0.736778238244
-0.767007983153
0.672321920729
0.0556060597496
-0.340945469966
0.252136119281
-0.396852920849
-0.683451384587
0.926232431375
```

Comment: myList.append(cm.ls('%s.cv[:]'%i , flatten = True))

Comment: flatten flag make your list by individual items

Comment: like this Result: [[u'curve1.cv[0]',
  u'curve1.cv[1]',
  u'curve1.cv[2]',
  u'curve1.cv[3]',
  u'curve1.cv[4]',
  u'curve1.cv[5]',
  u'curve1.cv[6]',
  u'curve1.cv[7]',
  u'curve1.cv[8]',
  u'curve1.cv[9]',
  u'curve1.cv[10]',
  u'curve1.cv[11]',
  u'curve1.cv[12]',
  u'curve1.cv[13]',
  u'curve1.cv[14]',
  u'curve1.cv[15]']]

Comment: Well if that is what `List` is equal to then what you're essentially typing in is `['c1.cv[1]']".cv["0"].xValue"`. There's a lot of types mixing and you have the actual cv in there twice.

Comment: i wanna increment .cv["this zero"]

Comment: do you have skype id?

Comment: i'm tired of this one nobody can help me  :-(

Comment: you were right.it's increment itself. but this is the new error that i got:   # Error: line 1: Invalid arguments for flag 'v'.  Expected float, got [ float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float ]
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<maya console>", line 1, in <module>
#   File "<maya console>", line 4, in randomize
# TypeError: Invalid arguments for flag 'v'.  Expected float, got [ float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float ] #

Comment: thank you but i need this setKeyframe command. your command just move cvs but it can't animate them i think

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all you're not even set up for animation. You need something to drive it. Right now if you set your keyframe all this will be happening on one frame. You could do something like:

```
time = cm.currentTime(q=1)
for i in range(10):
    cm.setAttr(myCVs[0]+".xValue", random.choice(test))
    cm.setKeyframe(myCurve, shape=1, controlPoints=1)
    time = cm.currentTime(time + 1)
```

Or you could plug i into the `time` flag of `cm.setKeyframe`. This way it keyframes the whole curve, the transform, shape, and control points. And you wouldn't have to worry about iterating through all of them. Set the value first then set the keyframe, just like you would if you were actually animating.